# MySQL lost connection when try to load local file

Tags: mysql

I am trying to load a local file into MySQL, but it is wired to have this issue (other files are OK, only this data file have a problem like this):

```
mysql>
mysql> load data infile '/home/tmp/supplier.tbl' into table SUPPLIER FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|';
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query
mysql> load data infile '/home/tmp/supplier.tbl' into table SUPPLIER FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|';
ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
Connection id:    1
Current database: wiki

ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query
mysql>
```

This `supplier.tbl` is about `300000` lines, each line is a record separated by `|`, the total file size is about `41 MB`.

Here's some samples in it :

`1|Supplier#000000001| N kD4on9OM Ipw3,gf0JBoQDd7tgrzrddZ|17|27-918-335-1736|5755.94|each slyly above the careful|
2|Supplier#000000002|89eJ5ksX3ImxJQBvxObC,|5|15-679-861-2259|4032.68| slyly bold instructions. idle dependen|
3|Supplier#000000003|q1,G3Pj6OjIuUYfUoH18BFTKP5aU9bEV3|1|11-383-516-1199|4192.40|blithely silent requests after the express dependencies are sl|
4|Supplier#000000004|Bk7ah4CK8SYQTepEmvMkkgMwg|15|25-843-787-7479|4641.08|riously even requests above the exp|
5|Supplier#000000005|Gcdm2rJRzl5qlTVzc|11|21-151-690-3663|-283.84|. slyly regular pinto bea|`

#### EDIT

The `lost connection error` shows immediately after I press enter button...

Comment: May we ask how large is the file `supplier.tbl`?  Are the other files which work roughly the same size?

Comment: can you share the tbl file?

Comment: I've updated my question, thanks, guys.

Comment: i suspect the lost of connection is due to the long process time. You can split the big file into multiple smaller files and load one smaller file at one time.